# Eclipse - corresponding code for console output

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to find the code responsible for any given console output in eclipse? I have a system.out.print call somewhere and i can't remember where i put it :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just search for the text?

This page nicely explains a few ways to search for text in Eclipse.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/searching-for-text-in-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

I usually do a CTRL+F for System.out.print and let it go where it will.

Answer (score 0):

OMG,

Just copy your output and use "Find in Files" menu option ;-)

HINT:

Use CTRL + C keys to copy your output.

Comment: I'm trying to find a line of code that prints a variable, there is no literal text in the print so that is not going to help much...